# Mocking req.user object for MochaJS tests

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, passport.js, chai

In one of my ExpressJS routes, I'm using PassportJS' HTTP Bearer Strategy and Local Strategy together. It means user must be logged in and must have a bearer token to reach that route.

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/login');
}
app.route('/api/someaction')
        .get(passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
      console.log(req.user.userID);
});
```

When I browse to this route with my browser or with Postman (after setting cookies for local strategy) it's working as expected.

Now I need to write integration tests for this route with MochaJS/ChaiJS. This is my test file:

```
var server = require('../app.js');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var should = chai.should();
var expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(chaiHttp);

  describe('...', () => {
      it('...', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/api/someaction')
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer 123')
            .end((err, res) => {
              // asserts here
              done();
            });
      });
});
```

While testing this file with MochaJS, `req.user.userID` in `/api/someaction` is always undefined.

How can I mock PassportJS strategies to get a `req.user` object inside route?

Comment: did you figure this out? right now I am just using a call to login and then reusing that server object. Looks like you can just mock passport directly.